# クラスメソッドのエラー: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby

特異クラス方式でのクラスメソッド定義

初心者です。初めての質問です。
初歩的なことですみません。
特異クラス方式でクラスメソッドを定義しておりますが下記コードで実行しても
以下のようなエラーにぶつかってしまいます。

コード

```
class << Hoge
def bar
  'bar'
end
end
```

エラー

`test.rb:4:in <main>': uninitialized constant Hoge (NameError)`

一応調べてみたものの原因がわからず。。お手数ですがお助けいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: `Hoge` が何かのオブジェクトでなければならないと思います。メソッドをぶらさげるだけなら例えば、このコードの前に`Hoge = nil` のようなコードを書けば実行できると思います。何がしたくてこういうコードを書いているのか書いた方が良いです。 [DEMO](http://ideone.com/2VPs6w)

Comment: [クラスメソッドの定義の仕方](http://magazine.rubyist.net/?0046-SingletonClassForBeginners) を読んでみるといいかもです。

Answer (score 1):

エラーはメッセージの通り、Hogeが初期化(定義)されていないことを示しています。
ですので、Hogeを定義しましょう。
文法上、Hogeはクラスである必要はありませんが、意図しているのはクラスだと思いますので、次のようなコードになるでしょうか。

```
class Hoge
end
class << Hoge
  def bar
    'bar'
  end
end
```

なお、このコードはこう書くこともできます(こちらの方が一般的かと思います)。

```
class Hoge
  class << self
    def bar
      'bar'
    end
  end
end
```